# browser issue, ie is not refreshing the page when some action performed

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I'm using jsp,spring mvc for my application where i can create,update or delete a record. I could not able to see the changes getting effected once the application is created. The functionality differs in each browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a cache related problem. You could try to insert no-cache pragma to tell do not chache page to the browser.

It could be done by http headers or meta ([Solution1](http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_pragma), [Solutuion2](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/)).

Another way, but dirty, is to append a timestamp as query string parametert to make different url to the browser.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first way which you have suggested but that is still not able to update or show the recent changes made..is their any javascript to solve this issue as in chrome and ff it is working fine.

Comment: @participantjava try deactivating the cache in your IE.

Comment: @participantjava There are info save into session? It could be some issue related to cookies?

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza, i cannot deactivate the cache in browser as this is a web application which run multiple users will be using.

Comment: @Zeppaman, i cannot append any random query string as i am using spring framework and based on conditional check we say setViewName("index"); and the .jsp suffix is given in application-context.xml file. I cannot add any random query string to setViewName("index")..

Answer (score 0):

In the page that you are having trouble with, put this at the top:

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

This will force IE to stop caching it.

Comment: still facing the issue in IE9 inspite of adding the header /meta tags ,can any one suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: There's one more header to try. `response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);`

Comment: @ developerwjk -- still no luck,,just added and checked in IE, still its not showing the updated data. I need to close the browser and reopen to see the updated data. but in FF and chrome i can see immediately.

Comment: Does this involve Ajax somehow?  If not, this should have fixed it. But if it involves Ajax, its more complicated.

Comment: If it involves Ajax, add an extra parameter to your Ajax request, and make its value a random number. The server doesn't need to read that parameter as its only function to trick IE into not caching. Really IE will still cache, but each request will be made unique by the random parameter so the cache will not be read.

Comment: developerwjk--Yes iam using ajax and jquery too, but not for page submision, for some other validations like retrival of dynamic drop down values on change etc iam using ajax, while submitting the form, i'am using html submit button and in <form action="/path" > specified the path which i'am mapping at spring controller.